# Saving new Data to a Data Set

Tags: c#

I have searched and searched.

My application uses a database created with SQL Server Compact Edition.

How can I save data (add new rows only) to the actual database using my application.

Would I insert the code into the saveButton?

```
    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(obeject sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      EcoDataSet edata = new EcoDataSet();

      EcoDataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter cTA =
      new EcoDataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter();

      cTA.Fill(edata.Customers);
      cTA.Update(eco.Customers);
    }
```

Will that do the trick or should I add a TextChanged event to my DataGridView?

Comment: BTW, please don't just put "C#" at the end of your titles. That's what we use tags for on [so].

Answer (score 1):

`Update` only updates changed rows. You aren't writing anything because you're using two different `DataSet` objects.

You need to apply the rows in `eco.Customers` to `edata.Customers`, then do the `Update`.

You should be able to use [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx) to apply the changes.

Comment: Thanks! problem solved. And sorry for just putting C#. This was my first Stack Overflow post and I was unsure of what tag to use.

Comment: No problem. Just leave the tags in the tag section and out of the titles, and you'll do fine. This was a good first question. Welcome!